# Why DocumentBuilder.parse throws SaxParserException

Tags: java, dom, sax

The typical code snippet to create a DOM from an xml is as below:

```
Document dom = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("somefile.xml");
```

I was wondering why the `parse` method throws `SAXException` ?

I looked into the code and found that the `DOMParser` class `parse(InputSource inputSource)` method originally throws this exception up the chain.

Can anyone please help me understand, why `DOM` creation will need us to catch `SaxException` ? Isn't it kind of an oximoron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it internally uses some SAX APIs.

> Note that this class reuses several classes from the SAX API. This does not require that the implementor of the underlying DOM implementation use a SAX parser to parse XML document into a Document. It merely requires that the implementation communicate with the application using these existing APIs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html

Comment: First of all "DOM uses SAX parser" is kind of interesting. Secondly, I didn't find any Handler being called in the source code. So not sure if it actually uses traditional sax parser. Could you highlight some code confirming that DOM is using SAX parser behind the scene?

Comment: I wasn't able to find code using SAX parser, but I looked into documentation and found this: "Note that this class reuses several classes from the SAX API. This does not require that the implementor of the underlying DOM implementation use a SAX parser to parse XML document into a Document. It merely requires that the implementation communicate with the application using these existing APIs." I'll add it to the answer.